# Mysql query result is not giving me the right result

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database

I'm updating my php page each 5 seconds

```
window.setInterval(function(){ 
    console.log(<?=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from records"))?>)
}, 5000);
```

If I have 5 records in my table, the output will be 5,
but when I insert a new record, the output remains 5 unless I refreshed the whole page, then it will be 6..

What's wrong?

Comment: PHP runs on the server, Javascript runs on the Browser. You cannot access a new PHP variable once the code starts to run in the browser. UNless you use AJAX to go and get a new value

Comment: I believe you should use `ajax` for that purpose, as it can send a request to a php script and get a response without refreshing.

Comment: you can use ajxa or reload the page, but you should have clear what @RiggsFolly commented. This can be useful for you: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: Try AJAX reuest to fetch rows count dynamically from DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are mixing PHP with JS, PHP value is written on page load and it remains that for all the time you stay in the page.

You should use a Ajax request that request again the value.

Do a PHP page that only returns this value:

```
<?=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from records"))?>
```

Then extend you JS with something like this:

```
    setInterval($.ajax({
        url: 'your-url-with-php-result', 
        type: 'GET', 
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){                          
              console.log(result);
        }           
    }), 5000);
```

You need also to include Jquery to do this

Answer (score 1):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how PHP and Javascript work. Don't worry, it's very common when first learning web development!

When you use PHP to print things onto the page (for example the code inside `<?= ?>`), the code is executed **on the server**. Try viewing the source of your page, and you'll see that when the browser receives the page, the PHP code has already been replaced by its result.

This means that when your Javascript loop runs, it's simply writing out the same precomputed value repeatedly.

To accomplish what you're going for, you'll either need to accept simply refreshing the page every 5 seconds, or read up on AJAX. AJAX is how you can load new content **from the server** (so, anything from the database) without reloading the page. It's what StackOverflow uses to show "1 new answer to this question", for instance.

Answer (score 0):

you can not use php in javascript codes

you soulde save php in example.php and you call example.php in javascript code

your **example.php** like this

```
<?php
    echo mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from records"));
?>
```

and you can now get data from example around 5 second time by this code (**load is jquery function**)

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    setTimeout(function(){
     $("#showRes").load("example.php"); 
    }, 5000);
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="showRes"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are normally mix the concept of jaavscript and php .you can solve this very easily . by passing php value into ajax and that value u should catch in that javascript .Try viewing the source of your page, and you'll see that when the browser receives the page, the PHP code has already been replaced by its result.

write php code in php page like:-

```
    <?=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from records"))?>
```

and use js as different page . call that value as your requirement.
like:--

```
     setInterval($.ajax({
     url: 'your-url-with-php-result', 
     type: 'GET', 
     cache: false,
     success: function(result){                          
          console.log(result);
     }           
     }), 5000)
```

if u need some jquery then you also include that in your code .